# Nesting a string inside a list n times ie list of a list of a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, nested

```
def nest(x, n):
    a = []
    for i in range(n):
        a.append([x])
    return a

print nest("hello", 5)
```

This gives an output

```
[['hello'], ['hello'], ['hello'], ['hello'], ['hello']]
```

The desired output is

```
[[[[["hello"]]]]]
```

Answer (score 5):

Every turn through the loop you are adding to the list. You want to be further nesting the list, not adding more stuff onto it. You could do it something like this:

```
def nest(x, n):
    for _ in range(n):
        x = [x]
    return x
```

Each turn through the loop, `x` has another list wrapped around it.

Answer (score 2):

instead of appending you sould wrap `x` and call recursively the method till call number is lesser than `n`

```
def nest(x, n):
    if n <= 0:
        return x
    else:
        return [nest(x, n-1)]
```

Comment: This solution is interesting, but it uses recursion which is notoriously slower than a loop. Is there an advantage to this recursion? This solution also enters an infinite loop if `n` is numeric but not a nonnegative integer--perhaps you should use `if n <= 0` to handle that.

Comment: Yup - I've edited code. I'm pretty sure that for small `n` the method execution time won't be very longer. I treat this as different approach however I admit that `khelwood` solution seems to be better generally

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pythonic recursion approach:

```
In [8]: def nest(x, n):
   ...:     return nest([x], n-1) if n else x
```

DEMO:

```
In [9]: nest(3, 4)
Out[9]: [[[[3]]]]

In [11]: nest("Stackoverflow", 7)
Out[11]: [[[[[[['Stackoverflow']]]]]]]
```

Comment: I was just going to say that the "advantage" of @m.antkowicz approach is that it can be written in one line which looks cool so +1 for this. Though [khelwood](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40083055/1219006) approach is generally better

Comment: @jamylak I didn't notice that m.antkowicz's answer is a recursion method :-). Although it's more complicated than what it should be. And regarding the khelwood approach it's generally better yeah.<